# Excel Error-The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an Apostrophe

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

This function will export and format data to excel. However,  the spreadsheet output has some data error in green as described above- So I place inside the function a code to clear this up and this does not work. Thanks for your help.

```vb
Function frmatEx()
    Dim FileName As String

    FileName = "C:\FolderName"
    'Set xl = New Excel.Application
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
    With wb.Sheets(1)

        .Columns("E:E").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
       .Columns("A:DA").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
       .Rows("BE:BE").ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText = False
       .Rows("1:1").Columns.AutoFit

    End With
    wb.Save
    wb.Close True
    Set wb = Nothing

    xl.Quit
    Set xl = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Which part exactly "does not work", and how?

Comment: I see nowhere where you code should remove a leading single-quote.

Answer (score 0):

I will make a guess that this line is the problem:

```
.Rows("BE:BE").ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText = False
```

The [ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198182.aspx) is not a property of a range, but a global Excel option.

So you'd have to do

```
xl.ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText = False
```

but of course that will apply to all Excel files from then on.

Perhaps in a new question show how/what you are exporting, so the root problem can be solved.